# How would I add a method to this jQuery plugin pattern?

Tags: jquery, plugins

I'm using the following code as the basis for a plugin I'm working on for a project - it's from an article on Smashing Magazine located here under the heading 'A Lightweight Start':

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/11/essential-jquery-plugin-patterns/

It's been working fine for my purposes so far, but the rest of the article goes off on a tangent and talks about what jQuery UI widgets which I assume I would need the jQuery UI library for, which I don't really want to use.

```
/*!
 * jQuery lightweight plugin boilerplate
 * Original author: @ajpiano
 * Further changes, comments: @addyosmani
 * Licensed under the MIT license
 */

// the semi-colon before the function invocation is a safety
// net against concatenated scripts and/or other plugins
// that are not closed properly.
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

    // undefined is used here as the undefined global
    // variable in ECMAScript 3 and is mutable (i.e. it can
    // be changed by someone else). undefined isn't really
    // being passed in so we can ensure that its value is
    // truly undefined. In ES5, undefined can no longer be
    // modified.

    // window and document are passed through as local
    // variables rather than as globals, because this (slightly)
    // quickens the resolution process and can be more
    // efficiently minified (especially when both are
    // regularly referenced in your plugin).

    // Create the defaults once
    var pluginName = 'defaultPluginName',
        defaults = {
            propertyName: "value"
        };

    // The actual plugin constructor
    function Plugin( element, options ) {
        this.element = element;

        // jQuery has an extend method that merges the
        // contents of two or more objects, storing the
        // result in the first object. The first object
        // is generally empty because we don't want to alter
        // the default options for future instances of the plugin
        this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options) ;

        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = pluginName;

        this.init();
    }

    Plugin.prototype.init = function () {
        // Place initialization logic here
        // You already have access to the DOM element and
        // the options via the instance, e.g. this.element
        // and this.options
    };

    // A really lightweight plugin wrapper around the constructor,
    // preventing against multiple instantiations
    $.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
        return this.each(function () {
            if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
                $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName,
                new Plugin( this, options ));
            }
        });
    }

})( jQuery, window, document );
```

I now need to add a method to this but I'm pretty clueless as to how to do so.

The method needs to work in such a way that an instance of what the plugin is creating on the page can have a property dynamically changed by calling the method with a value via the console (eventually this will occur via some other process, but console is good for now).

How would I go about amending the code above to allow for this? Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, complex JavaScript can leave me a bit lost in the dark at times I'm afraid but I like to try to do things as 'best practices' as possible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The jQuery documentation strongly recommends calling plugin methods by passing a string to the main plugin method. This is to stop the `$.fn` namespace becoming cluttered by the methods of your plugin. So you do something like this:

```
$.fn.yourPlugin = function(options) {
    if (typeof options === "string") {
        //Call method referred to by 'options'
    } else {
        //Setup plugin as usual
    }
};
```

In your pattern, you already have the perfect place to define your methods: `Plugin.prototype`. For example, to add a `changeColor` method:

```
Plugin.prototype.changeColor = function(color) {
    $(this.element).css("color", color);
}
```

Notice the use of `$(this.element)`. That's because in the `Plugin` constructor, a property `element` is defined, and the element on which the plugin is being applied is assigned to it:

```
this.element = element;
```

That is the actual DOM element, not a jQuery object, hence the need to call jQuery on it.

So now you have a method, you need to add a mechanism to call it. Following the recommendations from the jQuery docs:

```
$.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
    return this.each(function () {
        if (typeof options === "string") {
            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1),
                plugin = $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName);
            plugin[options].apply(plugin, args);
        } else if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
            $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName,
            new Plugin( this, options ));
        }
    });
};
```

You can then call the `changeColor` method like this:

```
$("#example").defaultPluginName("changeColour", "red");​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Here's a [fiddle with a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/yucCG/). You may want to add some check around the method calling code to make sure the plugin has actually be instantiated on the element(s) you are calling it on.

Comment: This looks great James. Will give it a go now and get back to you, but very promising looking. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
Plugin.prototype.reset = function () {

};
Plugin.prototype.destroy = function () {

};
```

and so on. add as many options as you want

Answer (score 0):

Instead of starting with a boilerplate that's hard for you to understand, the best start is at the origins:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring